# Android TextView custom typeset causes gravity to stop working

Tags: android, roboto

### Update

This only appears to be happening with Roboto-Italic.ttf.  If you're running into this issue, try another font family.

---

I'm running into an odd issue when applying a typeset to a TextView. The app name, "Contact" is in a LinearLayout with `android:gravity="center"` set, which causes it to be centered nicely as seen in the "Before" image below.  When I set the typeface, it causes the gravity to stop working for some reason.  This is how I'm setting the typeface:

```
tvAppName.setTypeface(
  Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf"));
```

Any idea why this might be happening?  I've tried setting the gravity programmatically, but that didn't help.  Commenting this one line causes the text to go back to being centered.

### Before

[image: Imgur]

### After

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have run into this and using a different font isn't really an option, I need roboto italic.

Comment: No, I never found a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Roboto-Italic.ttf file from Google's website seems to be broken or incompatible in some way. Work-around is to **use the normal Roboto font but specify italic as the 2nd argument**:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Normal.ttf")); 
tvAppName.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

What this does is fake the italics by putting a skew on the text. So it theoretically does not look as nice, but it solves the problem of gravity and other layout attributes not working with the real Roboto Italic.